# onScrollChanged firing multiple times for scroll end in scrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview, onscrolllistener, onscrollchanged

I have implemented a listener class to detect end of scroll view referring the link https://gist.github.com/marteinn/9427072

```
public class ResponsiveScrollView extends ScrollView {

private OnBottomReachedListener listener;

public ResponsiveScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    View view = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    int diff = view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY());
    if (diff == 0 && listener!= null) {
        listener.onBottomReached(this);
    }
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}

public OnBottomReachedListener getBottomChangedListener() {
        return listener;
}

public void setBottomReachesListener(OnBottomReachedListener onBottomReachedListener) {
    this.listener = onBottomReachedListener;
}

public interface OnBottomReachedListener {
    public void onBottomReached(View view);
   }
}
```

Listener is set to scrollView:

```
scrollView.setBottomReachesListener(new GenericScrollListerner(this));
```

My GenericScrollListerner class:

```
public class GenericScrollListerner implements ResponsiveScrollView.OnBottomReachedListener {
private Context mContext;

public GenericScrollListerner(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onBottomReached(View view) {
    Log.d("ScrollView","Scroll end");
    String tag = (String) view.getTag();
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Scroll end with tag" +tag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

My issue is that onBottomReached is firing twice most of the times. How to handle this issue ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I found an answer without a tweak.

Extend Custom scroll view with 'NestedScrollView' instead of ScrollView

```
public class ResponsiveScrollView extends NestedScrollView {

private OnBottomReachedListener listener;

public ResponsiveScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    View view = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    int diff = view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY());
    if (diff == 0 && listener!= null) {
        listener.onBottomReached(this);
    }
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}

public OnBottomReachedListener getBottomChangedListener() {
        return listener;
}

public void setBottomReachesListener(OnBottomReachedListener onBottomReachedListener) {
    this.listener = onBottomReachedListener;
}

public interface OnBottomReachedListener {
    public void onBottomReached(View view);
   }
}
```

The above code will work

Answer (score 7):

This happens due to overscroll. Please add the following line in scrollview xml declaration

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

If issue still persist then use the following tweak

```
@Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        View view = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        int diff = view.getBottom() - (getHeight() + getScrollY());
        if (diff == 0 && listener != null && !stopTwice) {
            stopTwice=true;
            listener.onBottomReached(this);
        }else{
            stopTwice=false;
        }
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }
```

Comment: Which one worked? xml declaration or the tweak? @remyathekkuvettil

Comment: This should be the approved answer